# Issues with resizing divs that are siblings and flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is specific to chrome since this is a simplification of a problem we are facing inside an electron app.

This isn't a normal bug but maybe a misunderstanding of how flex-box resizes content and scroll positioning. I am wondering if anyone has encountered this issue before and has a solution.

The issue is that I have a parent div that is flex-direction column that contains 2 children. First sibling is flex 1 to take up the space, and the second sibling can grow and shrink. When the bottom sibling grows the top siblings content isn't pushed properly.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Scroll to the bottom of the top div
2. Click on the "increase height" button. Notice that the scrollbar is
   no longer at the bottom
3. Click the "increase height" button a few more times
4. Scroll the top div to the bottom
5. Click the "decrease height" button till it is back to the min-height
6. Click the "increase height" button. Notice that now the height
   increase is actually pushing the content up. It will continues to push the content up until the place where you last scrolled down

Here is a fiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/wzqbkLx4/
Below is the code from the fiddle

sample.html

```
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='content'>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
      <div>
        askldjfaslkdjflasdjflkasjdflkjasdlfjaslkdf
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='footer' id="footer">
      <button onclick="increaseHeight()">
        increase height
      </button>
      <button onclick="decreaseHeight()">
        decrease height
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
  function increaseHeight () {
        var el = document.getElementById("footer");
    var height = el.offsetHeight;
    el.style.height = (height + 10) + 'px';
    }


  function decreaseHeight () {
        var el = document.getElementById("footer");
    var height = el.offsetHeight;
    el.style.height = (height - 10) + 'px';
    }

  </script>
```

sample.css

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  div {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: This is not related to Flexbox, using `display: block` behaves in a similar way, as seen here: [fiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/1a20brtk/1/). As agreed I closed this as a dupe, to a post which were more related to what OP were looking for.

Comment: This comment is misleading as the behaviour is not exactly similar using display: block. Plus the solution to the problem is only achievable with flexbox

Comment: I can't see how it is misleading. In your question you ask about _resizes content and scroll positioning_, combined with _content isn't pushed properly_. That behavior is similar (not exact same though) whether one use `flex` or `block`, where neither keep content bottom aligned by default. When it comes to a solution though, where to keep content bottom aligned, Flexbox has a feature that can do this, hence we agreed to close the question with a link to my other answer.